# Hiding text after clicking on something different

Tags: javascript, html, function

My goal here is to have the riddles in my page to be shown one at a time. My instructor has shown us a way using JavaScript variables. in my HTML I have two riddles shown as an example:

```
<h5>Question 1</h5>    
<p onClick="revealAnswer('answer1','When it is turned into the teacher', 0)">When is homework not homework?</p><br/>
<span id="answer1" class="answers"></span><br/>
<hr>
<h5>Question 2</h5>
<p onClick="revealAnswer('answer2','An Umbrella', 1)">What goes up when rain comes down?</p><br/>
<span id="answer2" class="answers"></span><br/>
<hr>
```

in an external JavaScript, I have this code to expose the answers:

```
var isVisible = new Array();
isVisible[0] = false;
isVisible[1] = false;


function revealAnswer(answerId, answer, indexNum){
    if(isVisible[indexNum]==false){
        document.getElementById(answerId).innerHTML = answer;
        isVisible[indexNum]=true;
        console.log(answerId);
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById(answerId).innerHTML = "";
        isVisible[indexNum]=false;
    }
```

My goal is when you click on "question 1", it shows you the answer, but when you click on "question 2" the answer to "question 1" goes away, and shows you the answer to "question 2". I am entirely new to JavaScript, but my best guess is to either add a new function, add an additional "if" or "else" to the existing "revealAnswer" function. What are your best recommendations?

Comment: Is this code not working? What's happening?

Comment: it is working, I am just wondering if it is possible as I said, I would like question 1's answer to hide when click on question 2, as of right now the only way to get rid of question 1's answer is to click on the question again.

Comment: ah, I see. Jagadesh has a good suggestion. You loop through the other answers and hide them and then show the clicked answer.

Answer (score 2):

```js
 var isVisible = new Array();
    isVisible[0] = false;
    isVisible[1] = false;


function revealAnswer(answerId, answer, indexNum){
    if(isVisible[indexNum]==false){
 var spanAnswer = document.querySelectorAll(".answers");
  for(i=0;i < spanAnswer.length ; i++){
   spanAnswer[i].innerHTML = '';
                        isVisible[i] = false;
  }
    document.getElementById(answerId).innerHTML = answer;
    isVisible[indexNum]=true;
    console.log(answerId);
    }
    else{
    document.getElementById(answerId).innerHTML = "";
    isVisible[indexNum]=false;
    }
}
```

```html
<h5>Question 1</h5>    
    <p onClick="revealAnswer('answer1','When it is turned into the teacher', 0)">When is homework not homework?</p><br/>
    <span id="answer1" class="answers"></span><br/>
    <hr>
    <h5>Question 2</h5>
    <p onClick="revealAnswer('answer2','An Umbrella', 1)">What goes up when rain comes down?</p><br/>
    <span id="answer2" class="answers"></span><br/>
    <hr>
```

Here you go

document.querySelectorAll will not work in IE

here is the traditional code which will work in IE as well

```
function revealAnswer(answerId, answer, indexNum){
    if(isVisible[indexNum]==false){
    var spanAnswer = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
    for(i=0;i < spanAnswer.length ; i++){
      if(spanAnswer[i].id == "answer"+(i+1)){
      spanAnswer[i].innerHTML = '';
      }
    }
    document.getElementById(answerId).innerHTML = answer;
    isVisible[indexNum]=true;
    console.log(answerId);
    }
    else{
    document.getElementById(answerId).innerHTML = "";
    isVisible[indexNum]=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: in your loop, you should also have `isVisible[i] = false`

Comment: Thanks on that helpful code Jagadesh. While copy and pasting is one thing, you wouldn't mind breaking down what some of the key things are in that code to help me understand it? yts mentioned that it "loops through the answers, then hides them as you click on a different question"

Comment: @StevenLedoux : Yeah i am looping throwing the answers , setting empty string ( clearing it  ) and setting corresponding answer to that particular question.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery would make your life much easier. Go take a look at this : http://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/jquery_hide_show.asp

To hide or show elements using Jquery you only have to do is give an id to your HTML elements as follows : `<button id="hide">ButtonHide</button>`

And then call an event on that button in JQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("#hide").hide();
    });
});
```

The `#`is a direct reference to the ID in your html making it easy to access it from your jquery.

If you wanted to hide the answer using jquery all you would have to do is :

1. Give and ID to it:

   `<p id="Question1Answer">blablabla</p>`
   `<p id="Question2">blablabla</p>`
2. Set an event on question 2

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#Question2").click(function(){
           $("#Question1Answer").hide();
       });
   });
   ```

To make it clearer how to inlcude this into your code go check the link I posted at the top of the answer

Go check on the following link how to include Jquery : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: This user is learning JavaScript. Using JQuery won't help him learn how it really works.

Comment: The more he knows the better. Jquery is an amazing tool that he should know about as it has many amazing features.

Comment: I am thankful for the input on using JQuery. Maybe our instructor may touch base with it, but I enjoy learning what each little thing can do. Even if the code may be tedious at times where a short string of JQuery code can do what one long string of JavaScript can do as well.

Comment: @micbobo True, but I don't think JQuery should be used systematically, especially for such a simple task. But I'm probably just bashing the library because I don't like it much, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach.  It toggles the visibility of the current answer, and then it hides all the other answers.

This simplifies the HTML, because you don't need any IDs.  **[`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling)** grabs the answer that goes with the clicked question.

It also simplifies the JavaScript, because you don't need a global array to hold the visibility of each answer.

```js
function revealAnswer(p) {
  var ans= p.nextElementSibling,
      all= document.querySelectorAll('.answers');
  ans.classList.toggle('visible');
  for(var i = 0 ; i < all.length ; i++) {
    if(all[i] !== ans) all[i].classList.remove('visible');
  }
}
```

```css
.answers {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h5>Question 1</h5>    
<p onClick="revealAnswer(this)">When is homework not homework?</p>
<p class="answers">When it is turned into the teacher</p>
<hr>
<h5>Question 2</h5>
<p onClick="revealAnswer(this)">What goes up when rain comes down?</p>
<p class="answers">An Umbrella</p>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know two ways to do this. One would be to put invisible radiobuttons on the page and to write the questions in their labels, but that's quite a peculiar hack. Let's do something simpler.

Instead of storing the state of all answers, you could just store which one is visible. Then, when you click on a question, the currently visible answer is hidden and the new answer is shown.

```js
var visibleAnswer = null;

function revealAnswer(answerId, answer){
    var answerElement = document.getElementById(answerId);
    
    if(visibleAnswer) {
        visibleAnswer.innerHTML = "";
    }
    
    if(!visibleAnswer || visibleAnswer.id !== answerElement.id) {
            answerElement.innerHTML = answer;
            visibleAnswer = answerElement;
    } else {
        answerElement.innerHTML = "";
        visibleAnswer = null;
    }
}
```

```html
<h5>Question 1</h5>    
<p onClick="revealAnswer('answer1','When it is turned into the teacher')">When is homework not homework?</p><br/>
<span id="answer1" class="answers"></span><br/>
<hr>
<h5>Question 2</h5>
<p onClick="revealAnswer('answer2','An Umbrella')">What goes up when rain comes down?</p><br/>
<span id="answer2" class="answers"></span><br/>
<hr>
```